# SQL Group on a combination of values

Tags: sql, grouping

I'm working a DB design regarding how a user launched something. 
My idea was to have timestamp (DateTime) column, and a method column (varchar).

This 'method' (varchar) could be anything:

- BUTTON_OK
- BUTTON_X
- APP_Y
- APP_Z
- etc

How can I COUNT the uses but group some values. In this case I want to have my result:

- BUTTONS: 20
- APP_X: 10
- APP_Z: 14

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: Currently for testing MySql but this could be MsSQL or something else. Hopefully this doesn't effect the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way of defining which 'methods' fall into which 'method group'.

One way would be to have a lookup table:

```
tbl_methodgroup

method_id    Method      Method_group
1            Button_OK   Buttons
2            Button_X    Buttons
3            App_Y       App_Y
4            App_Z       App_Z
```

then you could use:

```
select 
b.method_group, 
count(1) 
from
tbl_methodgroup a
  inner join tbl_method b on a.Method=b.Method
group by b.method_group
```

This method would have the advantage of being scalable as more methods get added. Rather than hand coding queries, which would need to be modified each time.

Comment: So it is not possible to this without an extra table?

Comment: Not reliably. You'd need to write some fairly nasty pattern matching code, and then possibly `UNION` a number of queries together to cope with the rules. It'd be a nightmare to maintain in the long term as the rules change or new methods are added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the table is tblTest, then the query will look like following:

```
 SELECT method, COUNT(*) FROM tblTEst Group BY method
```

Apologies if I missread question, last chance to make it right if you have consistency in the data and grouping scenarios you can do following:

```
 SELECT LEFT(method,CHARINDEX('_',method)-1), 
        COUNT(*) 
 FROM tblTest 
 GROUP BY LEFT(method,CHARINDEX('_',method)-1)
```

Otherwise Stuart Moore's answer is correct one.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do what @PowerRoy has asked for. They want to group by a 'group' of methods (look at the required results, they want all 'button*' methods counting together rather than seperately (ie; count of Buttons=Count of Button_OK+Count of Button_X)).